# MVC4 get request variable from URL

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 for the first time and I'm trying to create a WebService.
However, when I try this: `http://localhost:****/api/mycontroller/?number=1&id=7`
I have no way to retrieve the data from the URL.

How can I get those 2 variables?
`Request.QueryString["ParameterName"]` results in an error, it does not recognize this function.

Thanks.

Comment: add number and id params to your action method definition

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to the WebApi that allows us to build RESTful applications. If yes, then there is not even a `Request` object in an `ApiController` because the `System.Web.Mvc` is not imported. The way Controller method works in an ApiController is different than MVC Controllers in that api methods are used or called as HTTP methods. So if you have:

```
[HttpGet]        
public int Count(int id)
{            
    return 50;
}

public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

That won't work by default, without adding custom routes, because the framework sees both methods as the same. In relation to your question if you want to capture querystring in a GET other than the default `Get(int id)` you should define them as method parameters as Dave A mentioned, like so:

```
public string GetByNumberAndId(int number, int id) {
   return "somevalue";
}
```

And you can call the method just as you are doing it right now:

```
http://localhost:****/api/mycontroller/?number=1&id=7
```

You can read more about WebApi on it's [official site](http://www.asp.net/web-api). [This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) can give you a good push although it was written a year ago, it's still a good resource to start with.